# Trig integral $\int ( \cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x}) \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Assume we have:

$$ \int (\cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x}) \, dx$$

Two ways to do it:

Use $$\sin{x}\cos{x} = \frac{ \sin{2x} }{2} $$
Then
$$ \int \left(\cos{x} + \frac{\sin{2x}}{2} \right) \, dx = \sin{x} - \frac{ \cos{2x} }{ 4 } + C. $$
The other way, just see that $ u = \sin(x), du = \cos(x)dx $,
$$ \int ( \cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x}) \, dx = \sin{x} + \frac{\sin^2{x}}{2} + C. $$

Now the part I don't see fully is, why aren't these results completely equal?

Taking the 2nd result,
\begin{align}
\sin{x} + \frac{\sin^2{x}}{2} &= \sin{x} + \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{1 - \cos{2x}}{2} \right) \\
&= \sin{x} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\cos{2x}}{4}.
\end{align}

So you have to absorb $\frac{1}{4}$ into $C$ for them to be equal.

Shouldn't they be equal straight away?

Comment: Why should the two $C$'s be equal? (*Ceci n'est pas cette 'c'!*) When dealing with indefinite integrals, what's important is that you end up with two expressions with identical derivatives, which in this case they are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question boils down to this:

If $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$ and $\int f(x) dx = G(x) +C$ are both correct, then shouldn't it be true that $F(x)=G(x)$?

The answer is no.  $\int f(x)dx=F(x) +C$ means that (on the relevant interval, in this case all of $\mathbb{R}$) every antiderivative of $f(x)$ has the form $F(x)+C$ for some constant $C$.   The indefinite integral is really referring to a *set* of functions, namely all of the functions (on the relevant interval) whose derivatives equal $f(x)$.  If $F'(x)=f(x)$, then that set can be written as $\{F(x)+C:C\in \mathbb{R}\}$.  But the set of functions of the form $F(x)+C$ for some constant $C$ is precisely the same as the set of functions of the form $F(x)+22+C$ for some constant $C$, for instance.  Explicitly, $\{F(x)+C:C\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{F(x)+22+C:C\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  That is, if $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ only differ by a constant and $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $\int f(x)dx=G(x)+C$ is also correct.

Comment: Ran into an even more illustrative one:  $ \int{ \frac{ -2x }{ (1+x^2)^2 } } dx$ becomes either $ \frac { -x^2 }{ 1 + x^2 } $ or $ \frac{ 1 }{ 1 + x^2 } $. Both work.

Comment: @bobobobo: Good example.  If you have $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of the same degree, then polynomial division gives you $k+\frac{r(x)}{g(x)}$ where $k$ is constant and $r$ has lower degree than $g$.  Thus $\frac{r(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ have the same derivative.

Answer (score 3):

If you write

$ \int{ \cos{x} + \frac{\sin{2x}}{2} dx }=\sin{x} - \frac{ cos{2x} }{ 4 } + C_1 $

and

$ \int{ \cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x} dx }= \sin{x} + \frac{\sin^2{x}}{2} + C_2 $,

then you can see what's going on with the constants in your two cases($C_1$ and $C_2$). Being careful with choosing the notation is good for understanding.