# A contradictory integral: $\int \sin x \cos x \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals, fake-proofs

I've been thinking about integration lately, and I've come up with a question that I'm not sure how to address. Consider
$$
\int \sin x\cos x \, \mathrm dx = - \int -\sin x \cos x \, \mathrm dx
$$
I started with the integral on the left hand side, which suggests a typical $u$-substitution. Let $u=\sin x$ then $\, \mathrm du=\cos x \, \mathrm dx$. So the integral evaluates to
$$
\int \sin x\cos x \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}
$$
But the original integral also suggests an alternate substitution. Let $u=\cos x$ and then $du=-\sin x \, dx$. So now
$$
\int \sin x\cos x \, \mathrm dx =- \int -\sin x \cos x \, \mathrm dx= -\frac{\cos^2(x)}{2}
$$
So now I have that the integral evaluates to two different functions. I've tried playing with some different trigonometric identities, but I haven't been able to show that this is true and I'm fairly certain I haven't had any success because the statement itself isn't true. What am I doing wrong? How do you evaluate $\int \sin x\cos x \, \mathrm  dx$?

Comment: A similar older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33187/trig-integral-int-cosx-sinx-cosx-dx

Comment: Relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262231/686284

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only thing that you’re doing wrong is forgetting the constant of integration: your two antiderivatives differ by a constant, so of course they are antiderivatives of the same function.

$$\frac12\sin^2x=-\frac12\cos^2x+\frac12$$

Comment: OH. Obviously. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @chris: You’re welcome.