# Simple u-subsitution - Paradoxical Result

Tags: integration

If I were to try and take $$\int{\mathrm{sin}(t)\mathrm{cos}(t)dt} $$ I would either take $u=\mathrm{sin}(t) $, yeilding a result of $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{sin}^2(t) + C$, or I would take $u=\mathrm{cos}(t) $, yeilding a result of $-\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{cos}^2(t)+ C$.

These two results are *not* equivalent.  What just happened?

Comment: $1/2 \sin^2 t=1/2-1/2\cos^2 t$. And don't forget that we need always to add a constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A contradictory integral: $\int \sin x \cos x \, \mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233971/a-contradictory-integral-int-sin-x-cos-x-mathrm-dx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you evaluate the definite integral of $$ \int_{a}^{b} \sin(t)\cos(t) dt$$, then you get:$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin^2(b)-\sin^2(a)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos^2(b)-1+\cos^2(a)\right)$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos^2(b)-\cos^2(a)\right).$$ So while the indefinite integral might seem off, the definite integral has the same values.

Comment: Every time, despite the fact that their graphs are not equivalent?  Hot dog...

Comment: The fact that their graphs are only off by a constant implies that their derivatives should be equal.

Comment: Wait I get it lol.

Comment: Im just showing that regardless of which antiderivative you use, either the $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(t)$ or the $-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(t)$, you will still get the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

The answers are not *equal*, but they are equivalent. Remember, as Artem said, that the two answers differ by a constant. And antiderivatives are always defined up to a constant.