# Why are we forced to use the double angle formula to integrate $\int 2\sin x \cos x\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I tried it using the double angle identity
$$\sin{2x}=2\sin x\cos x$$

The answer that I got is
$$\frac{-\cos 2x}{4} +c$$
However I've also tried it using $u$-substitution.

I let $u=\sin x$. Thus obtaining $\cos x$ when differentiating. And cutting the $\cos x$ in $2\sin x\cos x$ out with the $\cos x$ in the denominator below $du$.

However the answer that I am then getting is : $0.25 - 0.25\cos 2x + c$. So as you can see there is the extra term $0.25$ there. Is the second answer deemed to be wrong? If so why? My book tells me to use the double angle formula but does not explain why.

Comment: Both approaches are correct. The $.25$ can be absorbed into the "$+C$". In other words, the two antiderivatives you found differ only by a constant, and that is to be expected.

Comment: Both of your anti-derivatives are correct.  This is explained by the fact that they only differ by a constant.  As your analysis indicates, you can use a substitution, rather than the double angle formula.  However, the book's *thinking* is probably that the double angle formula is easier, because just as you immediately know how to integrate $\int \sin x$, you can also easily integrate $\int \sin(kx)$.

Comment: I see. But what if I had limits of integration? Wouldn't I get two different answers?

Comment: Nope!  Try it and see: Note that if $F'(x) = f(x)$, and $G(x) = F(x) + C$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a) = G(b) - G(a)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple u-subsitution - Paradoxical Result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379788/simple-u-subsitution-paradoxical-result)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trig integral $\int ( \cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x}) \, dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33187/trig-integral-int-cosx-sinx-cosx-dx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers are correct. You can use double angle identity, as well as u sub for either $\sin x$ or $\cos x$.

The key lies in the +c. All the 3 integrals are a family of functions just separated by a different "+c". In practice, double angle identity is often used as it's more intuitive and simpler in some sense. But the other methods are perfectly acceptable, and not "wrong."

Comment: But you say that the constant of integration changes. Suppose i had limits of integration (let us say 1 to 2 ) for this question. My answer would be different, right?

Comment: It won't as the constant would get subtracted while plugging in the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Ohh.. OK. Thanks for the help. I am approving your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your method is not wrong.

All you need to do is just substitute
\begin{equation*}
c_{2} =0.25+c
\end{equation*}
and then you get the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \sin^2 x =  \sin x \cos x$$
so
$$\int \sin x \cos x \,dx = \frac{1}{2} \sin^2 x + \text{constant}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try graphing the two answers. You will see that they have equal slopes at each $x$ value, so they are both anti-derivatives of the same thing. Moving either vertically up or down does not change this (and can make them coincide). That is the $+C$, an *arbitrary* constant of integration.