# Shouldn't two different expressions for a general antiderivative be equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For the integral
$$\int 2 \cos x \sin x \text{d}x,$$
a $u$-substitution with $u = \sin x$ leads to $$\int 2 u \text{d}u = 2 \cdot \frac{u^2}{2}+C=  u^{2}+C = \sin ^{2}x + C.$$ On the other hand, using the double-angle formula $2 \sin x \cos x = \sin \left(2x\right)$, the original integral can be evaluated as
$$\int \sin \left(2x \right)\text{d}x = -\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)}{2}+D.$$
I was expecting to be able to find a relationship between the two antiderivatives in the following way:
$$\sin ^{2} x = -\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)}{2}+E.$$
But $\sin ^{2} x +\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)}{2}$ is not a constant.

The reason that I was expecting to be able to find a relationship between the two answers due to the fact that they are general solutions to the ODE $y' = 2\sin x \cos x$ and that transitivity of equality should imply that the two antiderivatives are equal.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262231/686284

Comment: If you're not sure if two expressions are equal (or differ by a constant), try plotting them first!

Comment: @Carmeister I originally did, but I must've made a typo because it wasn't a constant ><

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually,
\begin{align}
\sin^2(x)+\frac{\cos(2x)}2&=\sin^2(x)+\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}2\\
&=\sin^2(x)+\frac{1-2\sin^2(x)}2\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
for each $x\in\mathbb R$.