# Integrating $\int{\cot^5(x)}dx$ with the substitution $u=\csc x$ seems to give the wrong answer

Tags: calculus

To take
$$\int{\cot^5(x)}dx$$

I substitute $\csc(x)=u$, $du=-\csc(x)\cot(x)dx$

and then it seems like
$$du = -u\cot(x)dx \quad\implies\quad \cot(x)dx=-\frac{du}{u} \tag1$$
is it not?

but then
$$\begin{align}
\int{\cot^5(x)}dx &= \int{[\cot^2(x)]^2}\,\cot(x)dx \tag2\\
&=\int{(u^2-1)^2\cdot\frac{-du}{u}} \tag3\\
&=-\int{\frac{u^4-2u^2+1}{u}du} \tag4\\
&=-\frac14\csc^4(x)+\csc^2(x)-\log(\csc(x)) +C \tag5
\end{align}$$

which seems wrong.

I feel like my substitution is a sham, but I don't understand why. Where is my mistake?

(note: I know that the correct solution is to substitute $\sin(x)$, don't bother. )

Comment: The easiest way to check whether an integral result is correct is to take its derivative and see if you get back the original function. Give it a go, maybe?

Comment: The proof is in the pudding. Have you derived your answer? And does it match the function to be integrated? Can you find a few trig identities to reconcile the 2 answers. If so, then you don't need our help.

Comment: Heck, you're right. The last time I tried to take the derivative I made a mistake. Seems the solution is right, though it doesn't look like the one in textbook

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453558/42969)

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine. In fact, even [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+cot%5E5%28x%29+dx) agrees (once one utilizes the identity $\log(\csc(x)) = -\log(\sin(x))$).

If you wish to check it for yourself, differentiate it and see if you can do the algebraic manipulations required to get $\cot^5(x)$ back out.

> (note: I know that the correct solution is to substitute $sin(x)$, don't bother. )

Debatable at best. [Integrals can have many distinct paths to a solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262190/various-ways-to-calculate-int-sinx-cosx-mathrmdx), and those paths may even result in different looking solutions. Bear in mind the end goal is just to find a function that differentiates to your integrand, but there are infinitely-many such functions that all differ by a constant.

It might be the simplest and easiest solution, but that doesn't mean your method is "incorrect," just different. And mathematicians value the ability to take multiple paths to a correct answer.