# Different results in integrating both sides of $\sin{2x}=2\cos x\sin x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I feel like there is something I am missing here. When integrating both sides of the trigonometric identity $\sin{2x}=2\cos x\sin x$ I get different results.

The left side of course results in $-\frac{1}{2}\cos{2x}+C$.

The right side I solve with u-substitution:

$u=\cos x$

$du=-\sin x dx$

$-2\int udu=-u^2+C=-\cos^2 x+C$

While writing this question I noticed another identity $\cos^2 x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x$. So apparently the $\frac{1}{2}$ falls out because of the $+C$ resulting from indefinite integration? This is still a little confusing to me.

Comment: You are off by a factor of two in the right hand side.  You should have written $-2 \int u \, du = \dots$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trig integral $\int{ \cos{x} + \sin{x}\cos{x} dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33187/trig-integral-int-cosx-sinx-cosx-dx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to recall that $\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x }{2}$.

This is an indefinite integral. So, the constant term $\frac 12$ is not relevant.  That is

$$\int \sin 2x \,dx=-\frac12\cos (2x)+C_1 \tag 1$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int \sin 2x \,dx&=-\cos^2 x+C_2\\\\
&=-\frac12\cos 2x+(-\frac12 +C_2)\\\\
&=-\frac12\cos 2x+C_3\tag 2
\end{align}$$

where we absorbed the constants $-\frac12+C_2$ into a new constant and called  that new constant $C_3$.  Inasmuch as the integration constant is arbitrary, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent statements.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. I was thrown off by the cosines having a different power.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.   Although it can be confusing, you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Integration process gives you results correct up to an arbitrary  constant.

Both results are essentially the same.

$$ - \frac{\cos 2 x}{2} + C_1 = - \frac { 2 \cos ^2 x -1}{2} + C_1 = - \cos ^2 x + C_2 $$

That is why it is better to write $ C_1, C_2 $ for the integration constants.